# How to Set Path for Chromium Browser in SublimeText2's Slidebar Enhancement Plugin In Ubuntu?

Tags: sublimetext2, chromium, ubuntu-12.10

For Running PHP in SublimeText2 I Installed Slidebar Enhancement Plugin & PHPCodeSniff Plugin. 
But When I Try to Run By Pressing F12.It Gives Pop-up "Browser 'Chrome' not found.If Installed? Which Location?'

On Right Click of Any/File Folder Open With..Application...I Opened File"Side Bar.sublime-menu"

Here SetupPath For Windows Given. But How to Setup it In Ubuntu?
like, "application": "C:\Documents and Settings\tito\Configuración local\Datos de programa\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",

But How To Set Path For Chromium in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

To get the path of Chromium on Ubuntu open a terminal window and type:

```
whereis chromium-browser
```

Most likely you need the path starting from `/usr/bin`. In my case: `/usr/bin/chromium-browser`.